# Animación por esqueletos en juegos 2D

Tags: algoritmos, motor-de-juego, 2d

He visto juegos en que las animaciones de los objetos (mayormente el jugador) es muy fluida, lo que me cuesta creer que estén implementadas por secuencias de Sprites.

Encontré en algunos artículos que dividen por partes al personaje y animan cada una independientemente, lo llamaban animación de esqueleto, si recuerdo bien.

¿Podrían explicarme cómo funciona en juegos de 2D?

Comment: ¿cuando dices "otro sistema" a que te refieres? puedes poner un ejemplo.

Comment: He visto en otros articulos , el personaje los dividen por partes, y animan cada uno independientemente, lo llamaban animación de esqueleto, si recuerdo bien.

Comment: Lo siento, iba a responder pero la pregunta fué cerrada. Las animaciones por [esqueleto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation) son básicamente sprites que en vez de ser animados por secuencia son animados por transformaciones del sprite como rotacion, translacion, escala, etc. Esto consume mas CPU/GPU pero menos memoria, al contrario de las animaciones por hojas de sprites. La pregunta no es amplia de todas formas, este comentario es la prueba!!.

Comment: Gracias,  esta era el tipo de respuesta que esperaba. Tenia mis dudas al momento de la ejecución de la animacion, pero ahora veo que solo es sincronización de las propiedades que mencionas a medida que el objeto tome una acción determinada. Jajajajaa muchas gracias.

Comment: Votando para reabrir la pregunta (que no tenga código y pregunte sobre una metodología no creo que la haga una pregunta amplia). En caso de estar equivocado, por favor no duden en comentar

Comment: @Mariano no es solo *amplia*, es que *no está claro* lo que se pregunta. Hay múltiples tipos de juegos: solo *sprites*, solo *3d*, mezcla de ambos, ... y múltiples tipos de animaciones: desde efectos simples sobre los *sprites*, hasta animaciones *3d* complejas *en cascada*, donde indicas el destino de una parte del *objeto* y calculas que partes del *esqueleto* has de mover y como para llevarlo hasta allá.

Comment: Trauma - es cierto (no lo había considerado, aunque se aclara que es 2D)... @Islam, ¿crees que podrías acotar la pregunta según lo comentado?

Comment: @Mariano, tienes razón sobre lo de las 2D. Las gafas, que no las limpié hoy. Sigue siendo algo extensa, pero, junto con la edición, voto por reabrirla.

Comment: Una pena que no se haya reabierto la pregunta. Unas pinceladas de cómo aproximarse al tema que dices está bien para comprender y a mi personalmente la programación de videojuegos me produce grandes satisfacciones. Te recomiendo que investigues sobre los programas "Spriter" y "Spine". No obstante generar las animaciones por partes moviles no implica que no se puedan usar con una hoja de sprites, es más. se deben usar las dos formas de animación debido al coste de los conceptos FDD e IK si tienes muchas entidades en pantalla. Si quieres conocer más del tema puedes contartarme por chat.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n ¡Si! sería bueno contactarte por chat, pero creo que aún no tengo privilegios para crearlas, o no se cómo hacerlo : (   x.x

Comment: He abierto una sala para el tema [aquí](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51999/sprites-con-esqueleto-para-juegos-2d). Estais todos invitados.